# week number and year combination

Tags: excel

Several questions have been asked in the past on Weeknumber and Year in Excel, however, I have a specific question that I couldn't find the answer to.

I'm trying to get a combination of year and week number in the format of YYWW, so for example 1752, or 1801, based on a column with dates, something like this:

```
Date         Year  Week
01-01-2018   18    01
02-01-2018   18    01
...
31-12-2018   18    01
```

Year is simply determined by using the `YEAR` function on the date, and the week number is determined using the `ISOWEEKNUM` function on the date.
This is then followed by some further processing, summing data based on year and week number, and the  issue is that then also the data of the 31st of December 2018 is taken into account for week 1 of 2018, while the 31st of December is obviously not in week 1 of 2018, but in week 1 of 2019.

So the question is, how could I "fix" this, so how can I get Excel to give me 19 & 01 for 31-12-2018? Ideally I am looking for a solution that does not involve any VBA.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you try a conditional IF MONTH = 12 and ISOWEEKNUM = 1 use YEAR + 1?

Comment: Agreed with @Nick. Something like `= YEAR(A1)+IF(AND(MONTH(A1)=12,ISOWEEKNUM(A1)=1),1,0)`

Comment: @Nick: Yes that definitely would work. But my question was meant to be more general than I formulated it, I now realized. 01-01-2016 was in week 53 of 2015. How to fix that then, assuming I would want to use one universal formula?

Comment: Add an ELSE IF condition to check for MONTH= 1 and ISOWEEKNUM = 53 use YEAR - 1 . Extending @ImaginaryHuman072889 's example: YEAR(A1)+IF(AND(MONTH(A1)=12,ISOWEEKNUM(A1)=1),1,IF(AND(MONTH(A1)=1,ISOWEEKNUM(A1)=53),-1,0))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `ISO` week numbers the **Thursday** of each week will always be within the “isoweekyear”, so for any date, to get the correct year it’s sufficient to find the year of that week’s Thursday. You can do that like this:

`=YEAR(A1+3-WEEKDAY(A1;3))`

Comment: Now that was exactly the kind of smart solution I was looking for, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of other options that worked for me:

=YEAR(A1)+AND(MONTH(A1)=12;ISOWEEKNUM(A1)=1)-AND(MONTH(A1)=1;ISOWEEKNUM>=52)

=YEAR(A1)+SWITCH(MONTH(A1)&ISOWEEKNUM(A1);"121";1;"152";-1;"153";-1;0)

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, thanks to the feedback of Nick and ImaginaryHuman072889, I fixed it like this:

`=YEAR(A1)+IF(AND(MONTH(A1)=12;ISOWEEKNUM(A1)=1);1;0)+IF(AND(MONTH(A1)=1;ISOWEEKNUM>=52);-1;0)`

I preferred not to nest the `IF` statements for readability and because they will never result in a `TRUE` at the same time anyway.

Comment: Call me old-fashioned, but I like nesting if it avoids redundant execution.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `= YEAR(A1)+IF(MONTH(A1)=12;ISOWEEKNUM(A1)=1;-(ISOWEEKNUM(A1)>=52))`. Note the `0` in the else clause of the `IF` statement is not necessary, since the default else value is `FALSE` which, when converted to a number, is 0.