# Week number 53 issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table where new data is filled in at the top.
In column A I have the date and i column P is the year and week number.

The issue is that I can't find a good setting for week number.

Currently I have this formula in P2 (and filled down)

```
=IF(A2<>"",YEAR(A2)&" - "&RIGHT("0"&WEEKNUM(A2,21),2),"")
```

And it returns OK values except at year breaks.

[image]

I mean it is correct, but that is not what I want.
The data from that week will be merged with the data from the "real" data of 2021 - 53 (if that occurs).

How can I separate these values?
I think the best would be to make `2021-01-01 -> 2021-01-03` => `2020 - 53`. But if anyone has a better suggestion I'm glad to hear it.
I don't want to hardcode these values since I might get the same issue this/next year.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832412/week-number-and-year-combination @barry houdini's answer shows how to calculate correct year for ISO weeknumber.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the Dutch, but on my PC I seem to have different functions for calculating week numbers:

```
03/01/2021 => =WEEKNUMMER(B2;2)   => Value:  1 # 2 means that the week starts on Monday
03/01/2021 => =ISO.WEEKNUMMER(B3) => Value: 53
```

In English the names of the functions are `Weeknum()` and `isoWeeknum()`.

Comment: ISO gives me the same as WEEKNUM(date, 21) so it's not going to help. WEEKNUM(date, 2) gives actual_week+1 as value this year. Meaning 2021-01-04 is really week 1, but it gives week 2.

Comment: ? Are you saying that the same functions give different resuls? I'm working with Excel 365, what are you working with? By the way, you mention `weeknum(date,21)` in your comment. It should be `weeknum(date,2)`, isn't it? (`2` meaning that the week starts with Monday)

Comment: weeknum(date,21) is the correct result, with 2 you get the wrong result. Try it and you will see. It's week 18 today. With 2 you get 19 as result.